# Adding a single swift file to an existing objective-c project

Tags: ios, swift

I have an objective-c project. I want to create a single swift file in the project and use it to initialize and present a view controller which has been assigned the swift file. Note that i do not want to import a whole swift project. Just a single swift file.

I have added #import "MySwift-Swift.h" and anything else i could find in the web but non of them works.

Answer (score 0):

To create the file, **right click** on your project name and click **'New File'**. Then make sure you're in the *iOS section*, at which point scroll through the categories (I believe you can find it in 'Source') and click **'Swift File'**.

Name it whatever you would like and make sure that it's a **subclass of UIViewController**. Then in your storyboard, in the inspector, change the class to what you named your file.

Hope this helps,

**Will**

Comment: ok thanks for the answer. Ive already got it working up to this point. But what if i wanted to use this swift class inside an objective c class? i want to import it and then use it to present the viewcontroller programmatically.